# custom database into project

Tags: android, database

I have finished the notepad tutorial on the android site. I did this because i want to create a DB for my app. Once i finished i found out where the data is located in the DDMS. Then..
I downloaded the SQLite browser database i created a mini DB. Know i am trying to put this data into my project.

Can i put this new saved database file(i made with browser)into the notepad database file & and delete the old one. So when the emulator loads it will load my data.
Because i made a database with android notepad with all the code etc. with this SQLite browser i am thinking the code is done for me(table, columns,)

I guess am asking you is can i just make a full database with sql browser and just input it so how in my project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your database class needs to be specifc to your database, so you cannot just change databases on the back end and expect the handler class you wrote for the notepad tutorial on the front end to work properly with it.

That being said, you can create a handler to run your custom db.  It's rather round-a-bout though.  After you get the helper class created, you have to put your db into the `assets` folder.  In your db helper you need code to copy the file out of assets to it's proper home in your applications data directory.

You can find instructions on how to set up your database so the Android framework can use it properly as well as code for copying it out of `assets` to your data directory [here](http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/).

Comment: Thank you. dont understand why i was down marked for this QUESTION

Comment: I didn't downvote (I don't answer if I downvote a question, seems rather contradictory).  At a guess maybe someone thought you had not made enough effort on your own.  It's customary (and polite) to leave a reason when you downvote a question so the question poster has some idea of why.  Obviously in this case someone didn't feel like explaining themselves.